# Subscribe to newsletter with a check box selected in a custom form

Tags: newsletter

I have created a custom form page where customers can submit details like name, email, etc and all the details are stored in a custom database table. The form includes following input fields.

**Name Field:**

```
<input id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>" type="text" />
```

**Email Field:**

```
<input type="text" id="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>" name="email" />
```

In in the same form I have created another checkbox with subscription to newsletter option with the following code:

```
<?php
                        $email = $_POST['email'];
                        $status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($email);
                        if ($status == Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
                            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
                               ->addSuccess($this->__('Confirmation request has been sent.'));
                        }
                        else {
                            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
                                ->addSuccess($this->__('Thank you for your subscription.'));
                        }
                    ?>
```

In the Thank You page I do see the  **Thank you for your subscription**. message and the subscription does happens in Magento but for some reason the email that the customers entered in the email field is not being posted to the newsletter so how do I fix it.

**Update:**

I was able to post the email to Magento Newsletter email field by moving the

```
    if (isset($_POST['is_subscribed'])) {
        $subscribeemail = $_POST['email'];
        $status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($subscribeemail);
            if ($status == Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
                 ->addSuccess($this->__('Confirmation request has been sent.'));
            }
            else {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
                ->addSuccess($this->__('Thank you for your subscription.'));
            }
    }
```

inside **QuoteController.php** file of the module. Customer First Name is still empty so how do I post Name field as Customer First Name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get customer first name from `customer/session` and place it in the hidden field.

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

    // Load the customer's data
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $customer->getName(); // Full Name
    $customer->getFirstname();
}
```

or you can directly get First name in controller also.

Comment: As of now we have disabled customer registration and login function. I would like to get the name from Name input field that is filled in the form and post it as subscribers first name.

Comment: then you can get first name just as you got `email`